# Generic DeleteView is returning django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x04725628 - Django

Tags: django, django-views

Disclaimer: I'm just a novice trying to learn Django

Hello, I'm trying to refactor my code and modify all the views that I have created to be Class Based Views.
I have an issue loading a form with DeleteView that is showing the data and at the same time is disabled.
I have some success and the only thing that I cannot figure out how to do is to show the data instead of the message that appears now "<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x04725628>"

+models.py:

```
class Note(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
image_url = models.URLField()
content = models.TextField()
owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, default=8, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse(self.pk)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.title}'
```

+forms.py

```
class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Note
    exclude = ('owner',)


class DeleteNoteForm(NoteForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for (_, field) in self.fields.items():
        field.widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        field.widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
```

+views.py

```
class DeleteNoteView(DeleteView):
model = Note
template_name = 'note-delete.html'
form_class = DeleteNoteForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('home page')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    data['form'] = self.form_class(instance=self.model)
    return data
```

+urls.py

```
path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.DeleteNoteView.as_view(), name='delete note'),
```

+template

```
        <!--note delete data form-->
    <div class="form">
        <form method="POST">
            {{ form }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!--end note delete data form-->
```

If I use my view it works fine, but I want to modify it.

```
def delete_note(request, pk):
note = Note.objects.get(pk=pk)
if request.method=='GET':
    note_form = DeleteNoteForm(instance=note)
    context = {
        'note_form': note_form
    }
    return render(request, 'note-delete.html', context)
else:
    note.delete()
    return redirect('home page')
```

Could someone tell me where I'm wrong and how I can fix it or at least provide me a link with information to understand why this is happening?

Comment: Can you share the *full* traceback?

Comment: I'm going to expose myself for sure now, but if I understand correctly I don't have a traceback. When I hit the delete button it deletes the record successfully and redirects to home also. The program continues. The issue is how the information is rendered in the template. For example in the field Title in the disabled form instead of appears text ''Feed the dog" it appears  <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x04B15628> . Which I think is because I've messed up somehow the DeleteView and I cannot understand where

Comment: You don't even _need_ a form class there. You can simply display whatever you want in the template (the view passes the object in the context, so for example you could write `{{ object.title }}`, etc.) and simply write an empty form tag with a submit button.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will try this way definitely too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a reference to the model class in your `DeleteNoteView`, whereas you should use the object that is removed, so:

```
class DeleteNoteView(DeleteView):
    model = Note
    template_name = 'note-delete.html'
    form_class = DeleteNoteForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home page')
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #       user self.object instead of self.model ↓
        data['form'] = self.form_class(instance=self.object)
        return data
```

I would also advise to filter the `QuerySet` such that it is impossible for another user (a user that is *not* the owner of a `Note` to remove that `Note`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class DeleteNoteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Note
    template_name = 'note-delete.html'
    form_class = DeleteNoteForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home page')

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            owner=self.request.user
        )
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data['form'] = self.form_class(instance=self.object)
        return data
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. And thanks for the advice for the query set. To fix the Profile part will be my next step because now is nonsense. I wish I had asked the question here three days and 13 articles how DeleteView works earlier  :)